# owl carousel limits dots pagination

Tags: jquery, paging, owl-carousel

I have crated a carousel to show images inside div using below JavaScript:

```
<script>
    $('body.cms-page-view .owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        loop: false,
        lazyLoad: true,
        margin: 10,
        nav: true,
        responsive: {
            0: {
                dotsEach: 5,
                items: 1
            },
            600: {
                dotsEach: 3,
                items: 1
            },
            1000: {
                dotsEach: 1,
                items: 1
            }
        }
    })
    

    $('body.cms-page-view .owl-dot').each(function() {
        $(this).children('span').text($(this).index() + 1);
    }); 
    
</script>
```

The output of the paging is something like this

[image]

How can I apply changes to change above pagination to something like this:

[image]